# Is it possible to block webfont downloads but allow visitors to see them?

Tags: nginx, fonts

My question is in the title.

I purchase nice webfonts but I don't know how to use them on a site while preventing the possibility of downloading them. I'm not a charity!

Anyhoo, I intend to do this on an nginx server if that helps.

Comment: No, there is no way to use the font but prevent downloading. you can change font file name and font family name to confuse them who want to download.  And for sure it's not your job to protect stealing the font, you just bought user licence. Font owner will find out website using the font without licence.

Comment: I know it's not my job but I don't like the idea of someone taking advantage of me.

Comment: You've had your answer... don't use a web font if you don't like the idea of people being 'ABLE' to copy your font. It should be noted that Google alone offers 804 free fonts and there are 10,000+ on dafont, most people don't want to pirate fonts.

Comment: ...I *know* I've had my answer, I also linked to a post by a company that sells fonts that explains how they try to deal with it. I wasn't aware that Dafont offers webfonts, but cool.

Answer (score 2):

Well, [this](http://blog.typekit.com/2009/07/21/serving-and-protecting-fonts-on-the-web) seems to be the only way. Really, all I (or anyone) can do is create layers of defense. Ah well.

Comment: Yes, `Depth in Defense`. With enough knowledge of web technologies, it’s possible to circumvent each one of these steps.

Comment: Yeah, I don't fully expect to block motivated downloaders.